# How do I get the automatic instrumentation of opentelemetry to work with Redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

I'm trying to get the Redis traces to appear in Jaeger with my Spring Boot that is instrumented with

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-javaagent:/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar"
```

I'm using Redis with Spring Session in case that matters.  But with manual instrumentation using micrometer tracing I was able to get it working.

I've had the following environment variables

```
OTEL_JAVAAGENT_LOGGING: application
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: http://jaeger:4317
OTEL_PROPAGATORS: tracecontext,baggage,b3
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_COMMON_DB_STATEMENT_SANITIZER_ENABLED: "false"
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_COMMON_DEFAULT_ENABLED: "true"
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_LETTUCE_ENABLED: "true"
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_COMMON_PEER_SERVICE_MAPPING: "redis=redis"
```

I also tried explicitly adding this to `build.gradle.kts`

```
runtimeOnly("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-lettuce-5.1:1.31.0-alpha")
```

But I can only get up to the HTTP controller.

I can confirm that I am getting sessions being created after flushing the redis db

```
> docker exec b42c5e6cabee redis-cli keys \*
spring:session:sessions:64d2da7a-fa11-4cd5-a1ec-2622fbdd77c6
```

[image]